# How to debug the combined js file

Tags: javascript, debugging

My java script file on server is a combined file.  How can I debug it by loading my local files that are not combined?

Comment: What do u mean by *combined on server* ?

Comment: Probably just means multiple js files are put into one minified

Comment: correct, that's what I meant